# C++ injector with user input

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I have made a simple DLL injector that works fine (x64). But when I tried to upgrade it so the user can pick the name of the dll file through std::cin i haven't found a method that works. Either I get some sort of error on compilation or everything seems fine except that the injection doesn't work.

Code that works:

```
#define DLLPATH "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\folder name\\test_dll.dll"

bool InjectDll(DWORD pid, char* dll);

int main() {
SetConsoleTitle(_T("Simple Injector"));

wstring pName;
cout << "Enter target process name: ";
wcin >> pName;

DWORD pid = FindProcessId(pName);

if (!pid || pid == 0) {
    wcout << "Couldn't find process: " << pName << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

if (InjectDll(pid, (char*)DLLPATH)) {
    cout << "DLL injected successfully" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "DLL injection failed" << endl;
    cout << pid << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

But when I try to make the DLL Path come from user input it doesn't work (no errors but injection doesn't occur):

```
bool InjectDll(DWORD pid, char* dll);

int main() {
SetConsoleTitle(_T("Simple Injector"));

wstring pName;
cout << "Enter target process name: ";
wcin >> pName;

DWORD pid = FindProcessId(pName);

if (!pid || pid == 0) {
    wcout << "Couldn't find process: " << pName << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

char t_dll[MAX_PATH];
cout << "Enter the name of the dll: ";
cin >> t_dll;

if (InjectDll(pid, t_dll)) {
    cout << "DLL injected successfully" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "DLL injection failed" << endl;
    cout << pid << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Some help would be great. (finding the process through user input works fine)

Comment: Have you inspected `t_dll`? Likely it's composed of `wchar_t` values, but InjectDll requires `char`

Comment: I'm new to visual studio but when I hover my mouse over the variable it says "char t_dll[260]".

Comment: How do I know if it's composed of wchar_t values?

Comment: Activate the debugger. Put a breakpoint at `cin >>...`. Step. Inspect the var that is going to be passed to InjectDll.

Comment: I would try using a static cast to char

Comment: The problem might be that I need the full path to the dll file. Tried some methods on google on getting the directory to where the program is located in but when i printed it out it only gave a "C" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution.
My two problems were:

- I needed the full path to the dll
- The std::cin seemed to have messed up the spaces in the path when I tried to enter it manually when running the program.

**SOLUTION:**
I used GetFullPathNameA (the other GetFullPathName didn't work for me) like this:

```
char dllPath[MAX_PATH];
GetFullPathNameA(dllName, MAX_PATH, dllPath, 0);
```